# Оператор JavaScript, похожий на SQL «NOT LIKE»

Tags: javascript

Как записать not like в следующем условии? В данном условии приведен просто like.

```
var user = '${principal.username}';
if((user.match(/.*50.*/) || user.match(/.*sp.*/))){ ...}
```

Comment: Оператор НЕ — `!`

Comment: Это понятно. Но как его записать. Так?   user !=user.match(/.*50.*/)

Comment: Нет, там где вы проверяете условия: `if (!(ваше условие)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на выбор

```
if(/^((?!(sp|50)).)*$/.test(user))
if((!user.match(/.*50.*/) && !user.match(/.*sp.*/)))
if(!user.match(/.*(50|sp).*/))
```